# Serve rss feed with xml, php, and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, rss, feed

What I want to do is create an xml feed that can be accessed by going directly to the url (with some request parameters) and then serve the content as a feed.  What I'm having trouble with is the exact way to do this to meet my needs.

I have an ajax system already set up to pull data from web services and then parse it from xml into json and extract the data I need.  It will be simple enough to extract what I need into a feed, but I can't quite grok the right way to do this.

I've already figured out how to serve the page directly from a url using php and xml, so that I print out the xml I need to serve the feed.  What I can't figure out is how/where to put the javascript in.  The javascript is only needed to parse the data, so I believe it would need to be inserted somewhere between the php call retrieving the data, and the php code echoing out the data.  It's fast enough to happen on page load, but I don't know if this is allowed.

Anyway, I can provide code or more detail if anything I wrote is unclear.

Comment: XML clients typically don't execute JavaScript, so you won't be able to let JavaScript to any operations that affect the XML stream. It'll have to come from server side.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that, but it escaped me.